# Which one is correct: '3 hour journey' or a '3-hour journey'?

Tags: articles, grammatical-number

Which one of the following is correct (bold part)?

> It took us quite a long time to get here. It was **3 hour** journey.

or

> It took us quite a long time to get here. It was **a 3-hour** journey.

Answer (score 2):

> Rule 1. Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective.

Following this rule, 3-hour should be hyphenated.

Also, for smaller numbers, it's sometimes considered good style to write out the word instead of using the number, "a three-hour journey."

[Here's the source](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp).

Comment: Can article a be used?

Comment: Yes, Google "a three-hour tour" as it should be a well-known expression from  American culture.  :)

Comment: I suggest that you click on "edited" to see how to attach a link to the source      in accordance with the general requirements.

Comment: @Rompey thanks, saw your edit.  I'll follow that format from now on.